Sums of product of 3j symbol
Is the following sum known?
$$\sum_{l_1 l_2} \frac{ (2l+1) (2l_2 +1 ) }{4\pi} \begin{bmatrix} 
l_1  &l_2 & L \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
where the sum is over all integers $l_1,l_2$. The "matrix" is the $3j$ wigner symbol.

I imagine that the $2\ell+1$ is in fact a $2\ell_1+1$...
